# Linux FireFox console debug mode.

Tags: linux, debugging, firefox, console

I have embeded linux machine using fireforx for UI. But I could not open its console mode for debug. How to open debug console for firefox on linux?

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`S`

OR
Press `alt` then Tools > Web developer > Debugger